# Create Generic Method in C#

Tags: c#

I have the following structure:

```
public enum MyTypes
{
    Type1 = 1, 
    Type2 = 2,
    Type3 = 3
}

public abstract class class1
{
   int id;
   string name;
   MyType type;
}

public class class2 : class1
{

}


public class class3 : class1
{

}

public class class4 : class1
{

}
```

now what I want to do is to make a generic method , I want to give it the type of object say class 3 and it will create object from class 3 and define it's variables and return it to be able to add it to a list of class1

like that

```
private class1 myFunction (MyType t , int id , string name)
{
    T obj = new T();
    obj.type = t ;
    obj.id = id ;
    obj.name = name;
    return obj;
}
```

how to create this generic method ?

please Help me as soon as you can

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Those derived classes (class2 - class4) can not be abstract if you want objects instantiated from them.

Comment: ... and why the enum? If you do need an enum reflecting the type for some reason, set it in the constructor for the specific type (or even better, just return it as a calculated property).

Comment: yes I'm sorry for mis-typing , you are right

Comment: the enum will help me decide the type of the object that I will use , also type is coming from another class

Comment: if you do indeed need to specify a type by using an enum, see answers below suggesting variations of the factory pattern. If that's what you want however, it's not actually a generic function in the .NET sense of the word.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As Danny Chen says in his answer, you will have to modify your class definitions a little for it to work, then you could do something like the following:

```
public T myFunction<T>(int id, string name) where T : class1, new()
{
    T obj = new T();
    obj.id = id;
    obj.name = name;
    return obj;
}
```

This generic method requires type parameter `T` to be derived from `class1` and also to have a parameter-less constructor -- that's what the `where T : class1, new()` means.

Since `id` and `name` properties are defined through the `class1` base class, you can then set these to whatever was passed into `myFunction` via its parameters.

---

Some more things to note about `class1`:

- Consider making `class1` an interface instead of an abstract class, as it doesn't contain any functionality.
- `id`, `name`, `type` need to be public if you actually want to be able to access them.
- Usually, fields aren't actually exposed as `public`. Consider using properties instead for that purpose.

Answer (score 2):

No, it's impossible, because all these classes are `abstract` (can't be instantiated). We can't create an instance of an abstract class.

Comment: No it was my mistake , I have fixed it , only the parent class is abstract and other classes inherits from it

Comment: I think you meant "can't be instantiated" instead of "inherited from".

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you are asking how to create a [Factory pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee817667.aspx). This is exactly what this pattern is designed for: specify the type of object you want and it returns it to you.

Alternatively, you could use a switch on the types in your function.

```
private class1 myFunction (MyType t , int id , string name)
{
    class1 obj;
    switch(t)
    {
        case MyTypes.Type1:
           obj = new Class1();
        ...
    }

    obj.type = t ;
    obj.id = id ;
    obj.name = name;
    return obj;
}
```

A third approach is to use generics.

```
private T myFunction<T>(MyType t , int id , string name) where T : class1, new()
{
    T obj = new T();
    obj.type = t ;
    obj.id = id ;
    obj.name = name;
    return obj;
}
```

You'd call it like:

```
var obj = myFunction<Class3>(MyTypes.Type3, 5, "some name");
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is basicly the abstract factory design pattern.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern

do something like the following

```
private class1 createSpecializedType<T>(MyType t, int id, string name) where T: class1, new()
{
    T obj = new T();
    obj.type = t ;
    obj.id = id ;
    obj.name = name;
    return obj;
}

public class1 createMyType(MyType t, int id, string name)
{
    switch(t)
    {
         case Type1:
              return this.createSpecializedType<class2>(t, id, name);
         case Type2:
              return this.createSpecializedType<class3>(t, id, name);
         case Type3:
              return this.createSpecializedType<class4>(t, id, name);
    }
}
```

Code is not tested and should be considered pseudo code.

This will allow you to call createMyType and it will figure out which class you want by the parameters and return you the correct object.

PS: Of course the classes are abstract and cannot be instanciated. But I suspect this was an error introduced when copying/rewriting the code.

Comment: I believe you are missing the `new()` type constraint on `T`.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, `MyTypes` and the actual type of the class expres the same thing. In that case, you need to have some kind of mapping from your `MyTypes` to the actual classes, for example:

```
static Dictionary<MyTypes, Type> typeMapping = new Dictionary<MyTypes, Type>
  {
    { MyTypes.Type1, typeof(class2) },
    { MyTypes.Type2, typeof(class3) },
    { MyTypes.Type2, typeof(class4) },
  };
```

Then, you can use reflection to create an instance of the specified type:

```
private class1 myFunction(MyType t, int id, string name)
{
    class1 obj = (class1)typeMapping[t].GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes).Invoke(null);
    obj.type = t ;
    obj.id = id ;
    obj.name = name;
    return obj;
}
```

Comment: A switch would be nicer if all types are known at compile time. If you do need to manipulate the mapping at runtime, you can also have a dictionary from the enum to an Action<class1> to avoid reflection. Finally, if you do need reflection, Activator.CreateInstance is a nicer one. =)